# BATS test helpers can't be loaded in orb

Tags: bash, circleci, bats-core, circleci-orb

I'm have a custom orb, and for testing shell scripts I'm using [bats orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/bats#jobs-run). 
I'm including helpers into my test like in [their tutorial](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/blob/master/docs/source/tutorial.rst#:%7E:text=setup()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20load%20%27test_helper/bats,src%3A%24PATH%22%0A%7D).

Here is my orb test job

```
  - bats/run:
      formatter: junit
      path: ./src/tests
      timing: true
```

And here is my src/tests/utils.bats

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup() {
    load "test_helper/bats-assert/load"
    
    source "./src/scripts/utils.sh"
}

# 1 Should load file when
@test "1.1: config file given, required tag missing " {
    mkdir -p "/home/circleci/"
    touch "/home/circleci/.test.utils.config "
    config_file="/home/circleci/.test.utils.config"

    echo "NEW_PARAMETER=value" > $config_file

    SourceParameters "${config_file}"

    assert_equal "${NEW_PARAMETER}" "value" # Check for no exit error
}
```

And here is error that I get in cirleci
[image]

Comment: Right, but `bash != bats`

Comment: @Jetchisel yes, but in example it's using it in .bats file as I do, so I don't understand where is my fall, can you please give me more details?